# Is the druid Circle of Twilight official yet?

Tags: dnd-5e, druid

I love the Circle of Twilight for druids but I can only find it in a November 2016 pdf of Unearthed Arcana. Is it official yet or is it still in testing?

Comment: I'm closing this question because “is it out yet?” questions have a limited life: they either get obsolete answers (before it's out) or become obsolete themselves (after it's out). RPG.se is for “forever” questions, not current events. See [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6048/can-i-ask-about-the-witcher-table-top-rpg-beta) for a similar situation.

Answer (score 4):

## No

Circle of Twilight was never published in official content. Xanathar's Guide to Everything included 2 new druid circles: Circle of Dreams and Circle of the Shephard. All three of these Circles were in UA, but Circle of Twilight was not included in Xanathars.

Comment: You have a misplaced modifier as it sounds like you are saying the Circle of twilight was not included in UA rather than XGtE.

Comment: @DavidCoffron Good call.

Answer (score 2):

## No

It has not been officially published and remains as the original playtest from [Unearthed Arcana](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/UA_Druid11272016_CAWS.pdf).